# add tags by variable with tokeninput

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

Hi guys when i want add a tag by selector jquery not working, like result i have always one id
the code is the following:

```
$(".conversation").click(function () {
    var profile_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var name = $('#' + profile_ids).text();
        $(".tags").tokenInput("add", {id: profile_id, name: name});
                change();
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with this library, the documentation here is misleading. (Or the functionality has been changed, and the doc not updated.) I've only been able to use these methods when I've called them on a JS var representing the tokeninput field.

When you create your tokenInput, save a reference on a variable:

```
var ti = $('#myField').tokenInput('data.php');
```

Then you can try:

```
$(".conversation").click(function () {
var profile_id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $('#' + profile_ids).text();
    ti.tokenInput("add", {id: profile_id, name: name});
            change();
            return false;
        });
```